# Solution of an ODE when one of the parameters is large compared to the other

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given this PDE:

$$\frac{d^2Z}{dz^2}+\frac{\sigma'(z)}{\sigma(z)}\frac{dZ}{dz}-\lambda^2Z=0$$
, with $\sigma>0$ and finite throughout the domain, and with $Z$ subjected to the boundary conditions:
$$$$
$Z\rightarrow 0$ as $z\rightarrow \infty$; $Z'(0)=0$
$$$$
The paper I am reading says that, when $\lambda$ is large, the solution of this PDE approaches:
$$Z(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt {\sigma(z)}}e^{\pm \lambda z}$$

Could you explain to me why the solution approaches this form when $\lambda$ is large?

Comment: Is $\phi$ supposed to be $\sigma$ in the first equation? Also this is not a PDE.

Comment: Thank you! Somehow nobody noticed the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z(z) = f(\lambda z)/\sqrt{\sigma(z)}$. Then
\begin{multline}
Z'' + \frac{\sigma'}{\sigma}Z' - \lambda^2Z \\= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma}}\left[\lambda^2f'' - \frac{\sigma'}{\sigma}\lambda f' - \left(\frac{\sigma''}{2\sigma} -\frac{3\sigma'^2}{4\sigma^2}\right)f\right] + \frac{\sigma'}{\sigma\sqrt{\sigma}}\left(\lambda f'-\frac{\sigma'}{2\sigma}f\right) - \frac{\lambda^2}{\sqrt{\sigma}}f \\= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma}}\left[\lambda^2 f'' - \left(\lambda^2 + \frac{\sigma''}{2\sigma} - \frac{\sigma'^2}{4\sigma}\right)f\right]
\end{multline}
So if we define $\phi = \frac{1}{2}\ln\sigma$, $f$ satisfies
$$
f'' - f  = \frac{\phi''+\phi'^2}{\lambda^2}f
$$
If $\lambda^2 \gg \phi'',\phi'^2$ over the whole domain, then to lowest order we will have $f''- f \simeq0$, and so $f(z) \simeq Ce^{\pm z}$, which in turn means $Z(x)\simeq Ce^{\pm\lambda z}/\sqrt{\sigma(z)}$.

Note that this requires $\phi', \phi''$ to stay bounded. This is not a consequence of the boundedness of $\sigma$. For example, $\sigma(z) = \exp[\sin(z^2)]$ is bounded and positive everywhere but the corresponding $\phi'(z) = z\cos(z^2)$ is unbounded.

Comment: On the second line, did you just substitute $\frac{f(z)}{\sqrt{\sigma(z)}}$ into the equation and take the derivatives?

Comment: Would you mind providing the proof of the asymptotic procedure?

Comment: @Geophysics Yeah pretty much.

Comment: @Hans I rewrote the derivation somewhat to make the asymptotic part hopefully more clear. Is that better?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Thank you for the answer! Could you tell me how I can practice so that I can work on this kind of problem in the future? For example, I wouldn't be able to think of letting $Z(z)=\frac{f(\lambda z)}{\sqrt{\sigma(z)}}$

Comment: @eyeballfrog: Could you help me with another question, which is based on the result of this question? This is the link to the other question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2621620/asymptotic-representation-of-the-solution-of-an-ode

Comment: @Geophysics This is a bit of a experience thing, but having a first derivative term of the form $\sigma'Z'/\sigma$ strongly suggests a transform of the form $Z = f\sigma^\alpha$, where you adjust $\alpha$ to get rid of the first derivative term.

Comment: @eyeballfrog: Yes, this is much better. To make it more rigorous, it would be even better if you can derive in detail the justification for dropping the right hand side of the final equation. As a matter of fact, this will lead to the perturbation expansion in Geophysics' follow up question in his last comment. It is usually tricky to prove the perturbation expansion.