# Asymptotic Representation of the Solution of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

This question is based on the accepted answer of [a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2620992/solution-of-an-ode-when-one-of-the-parameters-is-large-compared-to-the-other). Given this ODE:

$$\frac{d^2Z}{dz^2}+\frac{\sigma'(z)}{\sigma(z)}\frac{dZ}{dz}-\lambda^2Z=0$$
, with $\sigma>0$ and finite throughout the domain, and with $Z$ subjected to the boundary conditions:
$$$$
$Z\rightarrow 0$ as $z\rightarrow \infty$; $Z'(0)=0$
$$$$
In the [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2620992/solution-of-an-ode-when-one-of-the-parameters-is-large-compared-to-the-other), it was shown by [eyeballfrog](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/395748/eyeballfrog) that when $\lambda$ is large, the solution of this ODE approaches:

$$Z(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt {\sigma(z)}}e^{\pm \lambda z}\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space (1)$$

The paper I am reading says that, because of this convergence, the solution of this ODE can be represented asymptotically (as to $\lambda$) as:

$$Z(z,\lambda)=\frac{e^{\pm \lambda z}}{\sqrt{\sigma(z)}}[1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n(z)\lambda^{-n}]$$

Could you explain to me why $Z$ can be represented this way, given the fact that it converges to the form (1)?

Comment: Are you missing a $\exp(\pm \lambda z)$ in that last equation?

Comment: @eyeballfrog My bad! I corrected it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first we need to prove the series really does converge. I kind of fudged it in the last answer because it's annoying and as a physicist I know the lowest order is the only one that matters.

So anyways, we go back to the equation
$$
f''(z) - f(z) = \frac{\phi''(z) + \phi'(z)^2}{\lambda^2}f(z)
$$
Now we suppose $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \lambda^{-2n} f_n(z)$. This gives
$$
f_0''(z) - f_0(z) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda^{-2n}\left[f_n''(z) - f_n(z)\right] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda^{-2n} [\phi''(z) + \phi'(z)^2]f_{n-1}(z)
$$
which can be solved order by order. The lowest order is
$$
f_0''(z) - f_0(z) = 0
$$
which we already know is solved by $f_0(z) = Ce^{\pm z}$. The next orders can be found by iterating
$$
f_n''(z) - f_n(z) = [\phi''(z) + \phi'(z)^2]f_{n-1}(z)
$$
The really annoying part is proving that the boundedness of $\phi'$ and $\phi''$ implies each of the $f_n$ scales as at most $C z^ne^{\pm z}$. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. The important thing is that this means $f_n(\lambda z) = C\lambda^n\alpha_n(z)e^{\pm \lambda z}$ for some polynomial-order function $\alpha_n(z)$, and thus
$$
f(\lambda z)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \lambda^{-2n}f_n(\lambda z) = C e^{\pm \lambda z}\left[1 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty\alpha_n(z)\lambda^{-n}\right]
$$
which immediately leads to
$$
Z(z) = \frac{f(\lambda z)}{\sqrt{\sigma(z)}} = C\frac{e^{\pm\lambda z}}{\sqrt{\sigma(z)}}\left[1 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty\alpha_n(z)\lambda^{-n}\right],
$$
which should at the very least be convergent whenever $\lambda > z$.

Comment: How do you go from $$f_0''(z) - f_0(z) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda^{-2n}\left[f_n''(z) - f_n(z)\right]$$ to $$= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda^{-2n} [\phi''(z) + \phi'(z)^2]f_{n-1}(z)
$$?

Comment: It's a restatement of the differential equation using the assumed sum form of $f$.

Comment: Could you provide an intermediate step? I tried but couldn't figure out where the $f_{n-1}$ comes from.

Comment: Note that the RHS of the original equation has a factor of $\lambda^{-2}$. This makes the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lambda^{-2n-2}[\phi''(z)+\phi'(z)^2]f_n(z)$, which is equivalent to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda^{-2n}[\phi''(z)+\phi'(z)^2]f_{n-1}(z)$.

Comment: Thank you, I got it! I still have some additional questions though:$$$$1. Why can we assume that: $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \lambda^{-2n} f_n(z)?$  $$$$2. I don't understand this line even a bit: $f_n(\lambda z) = C\lambda^n\alpha_n(z)e^{\pm \lambda z}$ for some polynomial-order function $\alpha_n(z)$; What is the role of a polynomial function here? $$$$ I believe it is my lack of background knowledge that prevents me from comprehending your answer. Could you please recommend a book/books that I can read to understand more of what you have done in this question? Thank you.